# Access Android's dictionary for autocompletion

Tags: android

I want to create an autocompletion function in Android, and I want it to lookup words from the existing language dictionary on the device.

What dictionaries are there an Android devices? (maybe several languages, and some user dictionaries?)
How can I access Android's existing dictionaries?

Answer (score 0):

There are **no APIs to access any preloaded language dictionaries** though, the IMEs bring their own Language dictionaries, **the system does not provide any dictionary data**.

There is a [UserDictionary](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/UserDictionary.html) content provider that

> **NOTE**: Starting on API 23, the user dictionary is only accessible through IME and spellchecker.

Unfortunatly you would have to create an IME or spell checker to access the users dictionary.